# Knock-Out Competition Web Part

Tags: web-part

Has anyone ever implemented a competition area within SharePoint that makes use of a knock-out progression visual mechanic.

My firm have set up a social area and to kick off the new year we're holding a soccer contest.  I'd like to represent teams progress witihn SharePoint if possible and am wondering how this may have been done elswewhere.

Something like this is what I'd like to achieve visually

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are wanting from a non-SharePoint context? (Maybe a screenshot of what you want to achieve)

Comment: Just updated with an image.

Comment: Some of our folks have done one of these in InfoPath

Comment: Anything that they'd be willing to share?  Or if they've documented it, could that be shared?

Comment: It wasn't document anywhere, I believe they accomplished it through filtered dropdowns.

Comment: @PirateEric I will also be glad to know how they achieved it using InfoPath.. Please do share!